# Move files in java?

Tags: java, error-handling

I am trying to move a file from the directory `workspce/TextInput` to `workspace/CPUInput` using this code:

```
String direct = System.getProperty("user.dir");
File file = new File(direct + "/FirstChar.txt");
file.renameTo("../CPUInput");
```

but on `file.renameTo("../CPUInput")` it give me a compiler error:

```
The method renameTo(File) in the type File is not applicable for the arguments (String)
```

If I can't use string arguments for `renameTo()`, then what arguments do I pass to the method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to pass a `File` instance like :

```
f1.renameTo(new File("../CPUInput.txt"));
```

Comment: I don't  think this will do what the OP wants.  This will be resolved relative to the `user.dir` environment variable, whereas OP wants to move the file to `workspace/CPUInput`.

Comment: @DavidWallace It's just for getting idea that argument for `renameTo` is a `File` instance not `String`. Of course he needs to put the right path for

Comment: Sure, but if you're going to give a solution with a relative path like this, what's the harm in including an explanation of how the relative path gets resolved?

Answer (score 2):

### With JDK6

Let’s start with the plain Java, JDK6 solution:

```
@Test
public void givenUsingJDK6_whenMovingFile_thenCorrect() throws IOException {
    File fileToMove = new File("src/test/resources/toMoveFile_jdk6.txt");
    boolean isMoved = fileToMove.renameTo(new File("src/test/resources/movedFile_jdk6.txt"));
    if (!isMoved) {
        throw new FileSystemException("src/test/resources/movedFile_jdk6.txt");
    }
}
```

### With NIO and JDK7

Let’s now look at how we can do the same using NIO and JDK 7:

```
@Test
public void givenUsingJDK7Nio2_whenMovingFile_thenCorrect() throws IOException {
    Path fileToMovePath = 
      Files.createFile(Paths.get("src/test/resources/" + randomAlphabetic(5) + ".txt"));
    Path targetPath = Paths.get("src/main/resources/");

    Files.move(fileToMovePath, targetPath.resolve(fileToMovePath.getFileName()));
}
```

### With Commons IO

Finally, let’s take a look at a solution with Apache Commons IO – probably the most simpler one:

```
@Test
public void givenUsingApache_whenMovingFile_thenCorrect() throws IOException {
    FileUtils.moveFile(
      FileUtils.getFile("src/test/resources/fileToMove.txt"), 
      FileUtils.getFile("src/test/resources/fileMoved.txt"));
}
```

This one lines will of course allow both moving or renaming – depending if the target directory is the same or not.

Alternatively – here’s a solution for moving specifically, also allowing us to automatically create the target directory if it doesn’t already exist:

```
@Test
public void givenUsingApache_whenMovingFileApproach2_thenCorrect() throws IOException {
    FileUtils.moveFileToDirectory(
      FileUtils.getFile("src/test/resources/fileToMove.txt"), 
      FileUtils.getFile("src/main/resources/"), true);
}
```

We looked at renaming in these code snippets, but moving is of course exactly the same, only the target directory needs to be different.

### Resource Link:

[Java – Rename or Move a File](http://www.baeldung.com/java-how-to-rename-or-move-a-file)

Comment: Eight years later... I just wanted to say +1 for the NIO approach. I'm not the beginner I used to be, and I've come to a great appreciation for NIO.

Answer (score 1):

try this out

```
public void renameFile(String strOldFileName, String strNewFileName) {
    File oldName = new File(strFilePath + "/" + strOldFileName);
    File newName = new File(strFilePath + "/" + strNewFileName);
    if (oldName.renameTo(newName)) {
        System.out.println(strOldFileName + "renamed to " + strNewFileName);
    } else {
        System.out.println("Error");
    }
}
```